# What's the syntax to automatically show map center and composer name on the map?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am trying to create some extremely user friendly print composer templates that have an awful lot of autotext  data that updates for each composer without having to manually type it in.

I have done this by using text boxes and inserting expressions for the required text. Currently I have file path, filename, project title, user , date and time etc but have not yet worked out how to add grid details etc.

I have got a grid with a frame and zebra around the outside of the map but it would be nice to be able to add a line of text that says something along the line of "Map centred on xxxxxx, xxxxxx" using the os grid reference, or something along those lines.

I would also like to add the composer name as an expression so its automatically updated